# why react native not support armeabi so?

Tags: react-native

why react native not support armeabi? Is beacuse Android-JSC not supply armeabi? how can i use react native only depend on armeabi? I changed the ABI to all in the  Application.mk file, but also tips that Android-JSC can't find so in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what You need. You can build apk for x86 and ARM devices.

To do so, inside react-native project go to *android/app/build.gradle*

change `def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture` to `true`

Then in `android` folder run command: *./gradlew assembleRelease*. After it's done, you should be able to find builds for x86 and ARM under *android/app/build/outputs/apk*

Comment: I only need build armeabi so file, not is armeabi-v7 or x86. 3Q